# How does this division approximation algorithm work?

Tags: c, division, bit-shift, approximation

I'm working on a game with a software renderer to get the most accurate PS1 look. As I was doing research on how the PS1 graphics/rendering system worked, reason for the wobbly vertices etc, I came across some documentation regarding the way they did their divide. Here is the link to it: http://problemkaputt.de/psx-spx.htm#gteoverview (see the " GTE Division Inaccuracy" section)

The relevant code:

```
  if (H < SZ3*2) then                            ;check if overflow
    z = count_leading_zeroes(SZ3)                ;z=0..0Fh (for 16bit SZ3)
    n = (H SHL z)                                ;n=0..7FFF8000h
    d = (SZ3 SHL z)                              ;d=8000h..FFFFh
    u = unr_table[(d-7FC0h) SHR 7] + 101h        ;u=200h..101h
    d = ((2000080h - (d * u)) SHR 8)             ;d=10000h..0FF01h
    d = ((0000080h + (d * u)) SHR 8)             ;d=20000h..10000h
    n = min(1FFFFh, (((n*d) + 8000h) SHR 16))    ;n=0..1FFFFh
  else n = 1FFFFh, FLAG.Bit17=1, FLAG.Bit31=1    ;n=1FFFFh plus overflow flag
```

I'm having a hard time understanding how this works, what is this 'unr' table? why are we shifting things?
If someone could give a more detailed explanation as to how this thing is actually achieving the divide, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Try http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It implements [Newton-Raphson division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Newton.E2.80.93Raphson_division) (Wikipedia link).

Comment: @OldProgrammer This question is off-topic for Code Review and is on it's way to being closed - Code Review doesn't do 'code explanation' or 'why/how does this work.'

Comment: @vexe: `unr_table` is a table of reciprocals for numbers in [1,2). Note the addition of constant `101h`: In conjunction with the table entry, this forms a 9-bit fixed-point approximation, where `0x100` is equivalent to 0.5. Note sure why they add `101h` instead of the value `100h` I would have expected; the additional increment by 1 may represent a fudge-factor that compensates for truncating nature of the following fixed-point math.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This algorithm is a fixed-point division of two unsigned 16-bit fractional values in [0,1). It first computes an initial 9-bit approximation to the reciprocal of the divisor via a table lookup, refines this with a single Newton-Raphson iteration for the reciprocal, x<sub>i+1</sub> := x<sub>i</sub> * (2 - d * x<sub>i</sub>), resulting in a reciprocal accurate to about 16 bits, finally multiplies this by the dividend, yielding a 17-bit quotient in [0,2).

For the table lookup, the divisor is first normalized into [0.5, 1) by applying a scale factor 2<sup>z</sup>, obviously the dividend then needs to be adjusted by the same scale factor. Since the reciprocals of operands in [0.5, 1), are going to be [1,2], the integer bit of the reciprocal is known to be 1, so one can use 8-bit table entries to produce a 1.8 fixed-point reciprocal by adding `0x100` (= 1). The reason `0x101` is used here is not clear; it may be due to a requirement that this step always provides an overestimate of the true reciprocal.

The next two steps are verbatim translations of the Newton-Raphson iteration for the reciprocal taking into account fixed-point scale factors. So `0x2000000` represents 2.0. The code uses `0x2000080` since it incorporates a rounding constant `0x80` (=128) for the following division by 256, used for rescaling the result. The next step likewise adds `0x00000080` as a rounding constant for a rescaling division by 256. Without the scaling, this would be a pure multiplication.

The final multiplication `n*d` multiplies the reciprocal in `d` with the dividend in `n` to yield the quotient in 33 bits. Again, a rounding constant of 0x8000 is applied before dividing by 65536 to rescale into the proper range, giving a quotient in 1.16 fixed-point format.

Continuous rescaling is typical of fixed-point computation where one tries to keep intermediate results as large as possible to maximize the accuracy of the final result. What is a bit unusual is that rounding is applied in all of the intermediate arithmetic, rather than just in the final step. Maybe it was necessary to achieve a specified level of accuracy.

The function is not all that accurate, though, likely caused by inaccuracy in the initial approximation. Across all non-exceptional cases, 2,424,807,756 match a correctly rounded 1.16 fixed-point result, 780,692,403 have an error of 1 ulp, 15,606,093 have a 2-ulp error, and 86,452 have a 3-ulp error. In a quick experiment, the maximum *relative* error in the initial approximation `u` was 3.89e-3. An improved table lookup reduces the maximum relative error in `u` to 2.85e-3, reducing but not eliminating 3-ulp errors in the final result.

If you want to look at a specific example, consider `h`=0.3 (`0x4ccd`) divided by `SZ3`=0.2 (`0x3333`). Then `z`=2, thus `d`=0.2*4 = 0.8 (`0xcccc`). This leads to `u` = 1.25 (`0x140`). Since the estimate is quite accurate, we expect (2 - d * u) to be near 1, and in fact, `d` = 1.000015 (`0x10001`). The refined reciprocal comes out to `d`=1.250015 (`0x14001`), and quotient is therefore `n`=1.500031 (`0x18002`).